# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!checkbutton"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an app that finds certain fields from a checkbox list.
I am stuck at `self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)` while calling `search` function. Although it works fine when running the line in the `__init__` it throws an error here.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def search(self):
        searched_field = self.search_box.get()
        found_indexes = []

        for i in range(len(self.name_list)):
            if searched_field in self.name_list[i]:
                found_indexes.append(i)

        self.text.delete("1.0", "end")

        for i in range(len(found_indexes)):
            cb = self.check_buttons[found_indexes[i]]
            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")

    def write_names(self):

        name_file = "names.txt"

        with open(name_file, "w") as file:

            for name in self.returned_list:
                file.write(name + "\n")

    def __init__(self, root, name_list):

        self.check_buttons = []
        self.var_list = []
        self.returned_list = []

        self.name_list = name_list
        self.start = 0

        self.search_box = tk.Entry(root)
        self.search_box.pack(side="top")
        self.search_button = tk.Button(root, text='Search', command=self.search)
        self.search_button.pack()

        self.scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
        self.text = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=10, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar.set)
        self.scroll_bar.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.scroll_bar.pack(side="right", anchor="ne", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        for name in name_list:
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(text=name, padx=0, pady=0, bd=0, variable=var)
            self.check_buttons.append(cb)
            self.var_list.append(var)

        for cb in self.check_buttons:
            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")

        tk.Button(root, text='Write names', command=self.write_names()).pack()
        tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack()

name_list = ["aaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "abcd"]
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, name_list)
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RO100162\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/RO100162/Desktop/proiect/eoIUPS/scrollbar.py", line 19, in search
    self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
  File "C:\Users\RO100162\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3423, in window_create
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!checkbutton"
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the tkinter root

```py
cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=name, padx=0, pady=0, bd=0, variable=var)
```

Similar to your other buttons

```py
self.search_button = tk.Button(root, text='Search', command=self.search)
```

Comment: Widgets default to the root if you don't pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the contents of the text widget, that causes the checkbuttons to be deleted as well.

This is from the official tcl/tk documentation on the text widget [[1]](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M49):

> The embedded window's position on the screen will be updated as the text is modified or scrolled, and it will be mapped and unmapped as it moves into and out of the visible area of the text widget. Each embedded window occupies one unit's worth of index space in the text widget, and it may be referred to either by the name of its embedded window or by its position in the widget's index space. **If the range of text containing the embedded window is deleted then the window is destroyed.** Similarly if the text widget as a whole is deleted, then the window is destroyed.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Do you know a way around this? I still can't figure it out.

Comment: @catza: the  way around it is to recreate the checkbuttons after deleting the contents of the text widget.